# Call a method when switchig views with UITabBar

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

Is there any way to automatically call a custom method when switching views usig a UITabBarController? Like, I want to he able to, when I set a NSString in one view in a UILabel, haave it automatically update a different label on a different tab with the same string. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, take a look at the [UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). All you have to do is register your object as the tab bar delegate and implement the `shouldSelect` or `didSelect` callback (the `didSelect` would be better a better choice). The callback will get called each time the tab bar switches.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` in `UITabBarControllerDelegate`. Implement that method in your delegate and do whatever updating you need to do in there.